# How can I download an excel file with sheetjs that the backend sends me?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-excel, sheetjs

I have been working with sheetjs for several days and I cannot download the file that it sends me, the library cannot process it and it blocks my entire page. What should I do?

[this is the file that the backend sends me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSRgJ.png)
this is the code i was using

```
axios.toExcel(datos).then((res)=>{
    const blob = new Blob([res])
    let a = document.createElement('a')
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    a.download = 'demo.xlsx'
    a.click()
})
```

How can I download an excel file with sheetjs that the backend sends me?

Comment: Maybe try `blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' })`

Comment: no, it's still broken, im triying with this another code: 
```
const res = await axios.toExcel(datos)
            var libro = utils.book_new()
            var wb = read(res, { dense: true });
            var book = await write(wb, { type: "buffer", bookType: "xlsx" })
            var worksheet = await utils.book_append_sheet(libro, book, 'sheet');
            utils.book_append_sheet(libro, worksheet, 'sheet2');
            writeFileXLSX(libro, 'name')
```